# Телеграм бот. Как различать анонимных администраторов?

Tags: telegram-bot, telegram, python-telegram-bot

я делаю бота и он добавляет пользователей в базу данных по id. но как быть с анонимными администраторами и пользователями которые пишут от лица канала? при запросе id у всех он одинаковый, мне выдает айди бота GroupAnonymousBot. Как мне их различать? пишу на telebot если что.